# Print a maze using only two characters

Tags: c, arrays, ruby, maze

I'm actually writing a program in C to generate perfect mazes. I found this code in ruby : https://gist.github.com/jamis/755866#file-recursive-backtracker2-rb and I translated it in C. Until there everything is correct and the algorithm can generate mazes correctly.

My problem is, those mazes needs three characters to be print. And i want only two characters to print it. I tried to modify the printing mode but it just don't works.

For example, i want a maze like this :

```
#################################
# #           #     #     # #   #
# # ######### # # ### ### # # # #
# #       #   # #     #   # # # #
# ### ##### ### ####### # # ### #
#     #     #   #     # # #   # #
# ##### # ### ### ### # ##### # #
# # #   # #   #   #   #     # # #
# # # ##### ### ### ####### # # #
#   # #     # # # #   #   #   # #
### # # ##### # # ### # # ##### #
#   #   #   #       #   #       #
# ####### ### ############# # # #
# #             #     #   # # # #
# ############### ### # # ### # #
#                 #     #     # #
#################################
```

And it prints like this :

```
 ___________________
|_  |  _   _______  |
| | |_|  _|   |  _| |
| |_  | |_  |_  |  _|
|   |___|  _|  _| | |
| |  _|  _  |___| | |
| |_|  _| |___  |_  |
| |  _|  ___|  ___| |
|  _|_  |  ___|  ___|
|_  |   |_  |  _|_  |
|_____|___|_________|
```

Anyone know how i should do to print the maze the way I want ? I can modify the dimensions of the maze or anything else, I just want to print with only two characters.

Comment: "but it just don't work" isn't a good description of your problem. Please show your code!

Comment: Then just use ’#’ and ’ ’ like in your example?

Comment: What happens when you, naively, replace `'_'` and `'|'` with `'#'`? Where do you need extra `'#'` or spaces?

Answer (score 2):

For your two letter maze you need twice the number of rows.
Replace each `|` with two `#` in consecutive rows.
Replace each `_` with a  in the first row and a `#` in the second row.
Replace each  with two  in consecutive rows.
If the aspect ratio then does not please you, also double the columns and use each letter twice.

```
'|' to '#' in row 1
       '#' in row 2

'_' to ' ' in row 1
       '#' in row 2

' ' to ' ' in row 1
       ' ' in row 2
```

Exanple, this would be an empty 1x2 labyrint with no inner walls.

```
 _
| |
|_|
```

Represented as

```
 #
# #
# #
# #
###
```

It faithfully copies the "gaps"/"holes" in the input top left and top right corners.
It also demonstrates the "aspect ratio" problem.

Here is the alternative representation I proposed for the ration problem.

```
  ##
##  ##
##  ##
##  ##
######
```

Or even tripled, to get it more "squarish".

```
   ### 
###   ###
###   ###
###   ###
#########
```

In order to fill the holes, you'd have to detect them in the input (that algorithm I consider out of scope, but let me know if you don't).

```
._.
| |
|_|
```

Then you can also replace them like `_` and get

```
###
# #
# #
# #
###
```

(*Judging by askers last comment, this is satisfactory. I feel I should give credits to  Aleksei Matiushkin for making me improve my answer.*)

Comment: Bars are to be replaced with a single sharp though.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Is that at conflict with my answer? "bar" would be the horizontal or the vertical?

Comment: Your answer recommends to _replace each `|` with two `#`_.

Comment: And I consider that necessary. Otherwise there would be a "hole" in the wall below each bar?

Comment: Ah, you meant “bar with a sharp _in both rows_”. Yes, that’s correct then.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks for your input. It helped me get the explanation clearer and made me use explicit representation in addition to description.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution has a glitch though. Check cell `[2,2]` in my output (the algorithm is the same.) It’s a wall in the bar-underscore representation, but a space in sharp-only :( Even worse, actually. It is completely wrong. Empty maze 1×2 will become 1×4 :(

Comment: Can you help identify the `[2,2]` cell?

Comment: Marked with “×” in my deleted answer. Anyway, it doubles empty rows down.

Comment: I see, that is no glitch. It faithfully represents the same problem which occurs in the input. The "bar-underscore" representation has the same wholes in all the places where something like "+" (or maybe a ".") is missing.

Comment: Ah, indeed, that is correct. But the number of rows should not increase in any case.

Comment: Doing your maze with the same number of rows I consider impossible.

Comment: Please edit your answer to a) ask for a solution with same number of rows (which I think is impossible) and b) filling the "holes". That would be a much more precise question.

Comment: Also please provide an example of desired output for given input with your question. If you cannot make one by hand, then please consider whether what you are asking for might be impossible.

Comment: My answer is wrong, as well as yours. By the same number of rows I mean empty rows should not double.

Comment: Please explain what is meant by "empty rows should not double". Is there an example of an empty row? @AlekseiMatiushkin

Comment: Yes and I provided it several comments above. Empty labirint, no walls, 1 column, 2 rows.

Comment: How would those two rows be doubled? Or to put it differently, how are non-empty rows NOT doubled? I stand by my opinoin that doing this without doubling ALL rows is impossible. I try to get OP to understand or disprove that by asking for a handmade correct output for a given input... @AlekseiMatiushkin

Comment: Hmm, I think I start to understand what you mean. Give me a little time. @AlekseiMatiushkin

Comment: I love you ! That was exactly what's i wanted, thank you sooo much

Comment: I used the good discussion foundation by @AlekseiMatiushkin  (empty 1x2) to elaborate on the problems I see. He pointed out the "doubling of emtpy rows". Which I don't see. Because of your last comment I assume that you do not see that problem either. Aleksei, I still would appreciate your input to help me see the doubling of rows. Maybe my view ("no **inner** walls) and its difference to yours ("no walls **at all**") is the key?

Comment: I will post a proof that the required conversion is impossible in 10 minutes.

Comment: Posted a proof.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion in the question **is not possible**.

That is because in the original representation the horizontal walls have **zero height** and in the sharp-only representation they took a cell to represent.

Consider the following maze:

```
----
| _|
|  |
----
```

In the left column, we have two cells and in the right column, we have three cells. When represented with a monospaced wall height, the whole maze does not remain *rectangular*.

That said, there is no isomorphic transformation of the maze with bars and underscores to the maze where all the walls have a monospaced width and height. ⨞

Comment: I like the clarity of the proof of what I suspected immediatly. Very helpful. A clear proof always outshines a "I suspect". ;-)

Comment: But there is, if you use an extra row and an extra column in the top and left of the labyrinth.  You can use two cell and, has normally the cells are almost twice as tall as wide. you'll get almost square cells.  If you have almost square cells, then it is better the 2x2 cell array.  And in the original labyrinth you also need an extra top line and left column to represent the top left walls.

Comment: @LuisColorado I do not follow. One cannot isomorphically transform the arbitrary shape into a rectangle and the result is supposed to be the rectangle **with monospaced width and height cells**, that said a true rectangle. 2×7 original maze with zero and seven horizontal walls in the first and second columns respectively is 2×[7,13] in monospaced representation.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, you probably don't follow, see my answer and you'll get onto it.  You can give a 2x2 cell size, as shown there, with a top left cell showing the cell interior, a right wall showing the right wall, a bottom left cell showing the lower wall and a bottom right showing a filled cell (a column?) and you'll get it with **monospaced width and height cells**.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, indeed, in my answer I give 2x1 to the cell interior, 1 column to the vertical walls and 1 row to the horizontal walls (and so, the corners are 1x1)

Comment: @LuisColorado to check why your solution is incorrect, simply follow the first column down. Compare the number of moves to reach the bottom. Also, you made me think it is indeed possible. We need empty cells that are jumped over between each row. To make is visually OK, we might make walls of size 1 and voids of size 1, but _earth_ where one could step—of size 2. That might work.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, sorry but your reasoning is based on a premise that simply is false.  You assume that the horizontal walls are zero width, but you can just give them some width and, instead of printing a different char for the interior with no bottom wall and with it, write a first row with all the interiors and then a second row with the walls.  Don't affirm so categorically that it is not possible because of that, as I have demonstrated in my answer, writing **the same maze** in both representations.  You know that you cannot conclude based on a false premise, right?

Comment: @LuisColorado all you demonstrated is the inability to read and understand comments. Your resulting maze requires more steps to go down in the first column than the original one. That simple.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, well, just continue telling that it is impossible to draw the maze.... :)  But I have provided code that simply prints it... any maze...

Answer (score 1):

You can represent your maze just using two character cells, taking into account that the walls to the right and to the lower cell are represented by the characters `_` and `|`.

On this premise, you will have four types of cells:

- A cell with no lower and no right walls, this will be represented by the sequence `" ."`.
- A cell with only a lower wall.  This cell will be represented by the sequence `"_."`.
- A cell with only a right wall.  This cell will be represented by the sequence `" |"`.
- A cell with both walls.  This cell will be represented by the sequence `"_|"`.

The upper wall and the left wall of a cell will be provided by the above cell and the left cell, respectively.

It is worth noting that you will need a left wall for the whole labyrinth and a top wall also.  They can be simulated by an extra row of `._._._._._....` and a left wall composed by `|` chars, giving to (this will be almost similar to the maze you posted as example.

So, if we represent the maze with an array of chars, a possible solution to the problem could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_maze(FILE *f, char *maze, int rows, int cols)
{
    /* maze is an array that has rows * cols cells.
     * Each cell is a bitmap where bit 0 represents the
     * right wall, while bit 1 represents the low wall.
     */
#define LOWER_WALL (1 << 1)
#define RIGHT_WALL (1 << 0)
    int r, c;
    /* top wall */
    fputc('.', f);
    for (c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        fputs("_.", f);
    fputc('\n', f);
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        fputc('|', f);
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            fputs(*maze & LOWER_WALL ? "_" : " ", f);
            fputs(*maze & RIGHT_WALL ? "|" : ".", f);
            maze++;
        }
        fputc('\n', f);
    }
} /* print_maze */

char *maze = "2102022221"
             "1130301031"
             "1211212103"
             "0123030311"
             "1030212311"
             "1303122121"
             "1030230231"
             "0321023023"
             "2101210321"
             "2232322223";

int main()
{
    print_maze(stdout, maze, 10, 10);
}
```

The program above prints the maze:

```
._._._._._._._._._._.
|_. | ._. ._._._._. |
| | |_| ._| . | ._| |
| |_. | |_. |_. | ._|
| . |_._| ._| ._| | |
| | ._| ._. |_._| | |
| |_| ._| |_._. |_. |
| | ._| ._._| ._._| |
| ._|_. | ._._| ._._|
|_. | . |_. | ._|_. |
|_._._|_._|_._._._._|
```

In this case, you need just the opposite, as you want, then you need to print two lines per cell, as the cell will use four character positions for each cell, divided in two rows of two characters each:  in the first row, you emit a space  followed by the content of the right wall, and in the next row you emit the lower wall, followed by the lower right corner (a column, full of content):

Next is the same program, but with the `print_maze` function modified to do the printing:
    #include

```
void print_maze(FILE *f, char *maze, int rows, int cols)
{
    /* maze is an array that has rows * cols cells.
     * Each cell is a bitmap where bit 0 represents the
     * right wall, while bit 1 represents the low wall.
     */
#define LOWER_WALL (1 << 1)
#define RIGHT_WALL (1 << 0)
    int r, c;
    /* top wall */
    fputc('#', f);
    for (c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        fputs("###", f);
    fputc('\n', f);
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        fputc('#', f);
        /* first row of the row :) */
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            fputs(*maze & RIGHT_WALL ? "  #" : "   ", f);
            maze++;
        }
        fputs("\n#", f);
        maze -= cols;
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            fputs(*maze & LOWER_WALL ? "###" : "  #", f);
            maze++;
        }
        fputc('\n', f);
    }
} /* print_maze */

char *maze = "2102022221"
             "1130301031"
             "1211212103"
             "0123030311"
             "1030212311"
             "1303122121"
             "1030230231"
             "0321023023"
             "2101210321"
             "2232322223";

int main()
{
    print_maze(stdout, maze, 10, 10);
}
```

which prints:

```
###############################
#     #                       #
####  #  ####  #############  #
#  #  #  #     #     #     #  #
#  #  ####  ####  #  #  ####  #
#  #     #  #     #     #     #
#  ####  #  ####  ####  #  ####
#     #     #     #     #  #  #
#  #  #######  ####  ####  #  #
#  #     #        #     #  #  #
#  #  ####  ####  #######  #  #
#  #  #     #  #        #     #
#  ####  ####  #######  ####  #
#  #     #        #        #  #
#  #  ####  #######  #######  #
#     #     #        #        #
#  #######  #  #######  #######
#     #     #     #     #     #
####  #  #  ####  #  #######  #
#        #     #              #
###############################
```

Please, next time, show your code, because StackOverflow is a forum to help you solve your programming problems, not to do your homework.  You say that you have converted ruby code into C, so probably your code has some problems.  It's better to solve your coding having a look at it.

## EDIT

I've written a complete program to illustrate three ways of printing mazes, including the possibility of printing using the line drawing characters available in unicode.  You can see it in [Github](https://github.com/mojadita/maze.git)

See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on this.